# Isolate containers in compose?

Tags: docker-compose

I have a compose stack and want to isolate containers from each other.

Diffrent networks is an option but isnt that buitifull

It feels not right to me. Is there any better way? Or is this the way to isolate containers from each other?

This is what i use at the moment:

```
proxy:
  network:
    - app1proxy
    - app2proxy
app1:
  network:
    - app1db1
    - app1proxy
db1:
  network:
    - app1db1
app2:
  network:
    - app2db2
    - app2proxy
db2:
  network:
    - app2db2

networks:
  app1proxy:
    name: app1proxy
    driver: bridge
  app2proxy:
    name: app2proxy
    driver: bridge
  app1db1:
    name: app1db1
    driver: bridge
  app2db2:
    name: app2db2
    driver: bridge
```